# Should I use a stored procedure, or just put SQL in my code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a select statement (see below) that I will be calling every night to update the data in one of my C# programs. I'm not sure if I should create and call a stored procedure or just add the SQL statement in my C# code. Which method would be better in general (efficiency, traffic maybe), and what are the benefits of one over the other?
Is a stored procedure overkill?

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.City, C.State
FROM Customers C
WHERE C.CITY IS NOT NULL AND C.State IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: A stored procedure is the wrong tool here as Gordon commented but it is never overkill to get code out of your application. This is part of separation of duties and well designed layered application. If you litter your c# code with sql both the application and the database are dependent on each other. This is not a good approach to software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a stored procedure to return values from a `select` statement.  A stored procedure gives you no control or even access to what the result set should look like.  This makes your code more brittle than it should be.

Instead, I would strongly recommend a view in the database.  Another possibility is a user-defined table function.

Comment: Ah, I actually did not know that about the result. Thank you!